# Can't install any OS

Tags: software-installation, system-installation, elementary-os

I can't seem to be able to install any linux OS. Previously I had two partitions in my disk, one with Linux lite and the other with Ubuntu. After various failed installation attempts of SparkyLinux, I switched to other OS's without any succes. Right now I'm trying to install Elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir.

The error I'm getting now is:

```
INFO: Extracting /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs
DEBUG: "unsquashfs" "-f" "-d" "/tmp/distinst.-9xdeX5hwseMH" "/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs"
ERROR: extracting error: archive extraction failed with status: exit status: 1
ERROR: erroed while installing system: archive extraction failed with status: exit status: 1
INFO: Install error: archive extraction failed with status: exit status: 1
```

but I think is different from the ones I've gotten before.

I'm using the custom install option, making a partition of 1GB for swap (marked for swap in the installed) and the rest for the root (mounted at "/"). If I need to provide more information, please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your CD drive is working properly?

Comment: I have tried it with different USB but still doesn't seem to work